# How to catch httpBody in WKWebView decidePolicyForNavigationAction?

Tags: ios, swift, http, webview, wkwebview

I switched from UIWebView to WKWebView in an iOS application. The webview loads a remote document which contains a POST-formular. Once the form is submitted a PDF is generated via PHP.

To be able to download and show this PDF properly I need to catch the POST content when the form is submitted - and do a manual URLRequest to download the file

I can catch the request as follows but the httpBody is empty in the code below:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: ((WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)) {

     var request = navigationAction.request

     if (request.httpMethod == "POST") {
           request.httpBody // <-- is EMPTY

           // as the httpBody is empty, the request below does not get the required result anymore

           Alamofire.request(request).responseData { response in
                ...
                let pdfData : Data = response.result.value!
                ...
                let docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: urlToLocalPdfFile)
                docController.delegate = self
                docController.presentPreview(animated: true)
           }
     }
}
```

This did work with the UIWebView before. Is there a way to access the httpBody in the code above, or any workaround to accomplish the PDF-download (as described above)?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @canister_exister I'm sorry that the question was not worded clearly - I updated the post above.

Comment: Try to add observer.  `webView?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "URL", options: [.new, .old], context: nil)`. and then `override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        
        if let newValue = change?[.newKey] as? Int, let oldValue = change?[.oldKey] as? Int, newValue != oldValue {
            //Value Changed
            print("NEW",change?[.newKey])
        } else {
            print("OLD",change?[.oldKey])
            
        }
    }`

Comment: when you are creating request can you try to set these param urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

Comment: @canister_exister What would that code do in relation to the httpbody content problem? For me it looks like an observer that detects URL changes (?)

Comment: @ShauketSheikh I am not creating a new request but catching the existing one, if I set the content type to json how is that solving the problem above?

Comment: WKWebView has this limitation. It does not allow us to see httpBody.